# PHP: Separate Array based on a value

Tags: php, filter

I have got the following array:

```
$raw = [
    [
        'prop1' => 'somevalue',
        'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
        'path' => 'used'
    ],
    [
        'prop1' => 'somevalue',
        'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
        'path' => 'used'
    ],
    [
        'prop1' => 'somevalue',
        'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
        'path' => 'used'
    ],
    [
        'prop1' => 'somevalue',
        'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
        'path' => 'used'
    ],
    [
        'prop1' => 'somevalue',
        'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
        'path' => 'used'
    ],
    [
        'prop1' => 'somevalue',
        'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
        'path' => 'new'
    ],
    [
        'prop1' => 'somevalue',
        'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
        'path' => 'new'
    ],
    [
        'prop1' => 'somevalue',
        'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
        'path' => 'new'
    ],
];
```

I need to filter through this array, preferably using `filter_array` to keep the code cleaner, I need to filter based on the `path` property. So I would end up with:

```
$filtered = [
    'used' => [
        [
            'prop1' => 'somevalue',
            'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
            'path' => 'used'
        ],
        [
            'prop1' => 'somevalue',
            'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
            'path' => 'used'
        ],
        [
            'prop1' => 'somevalue',
            'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
            'path' => 'used'
        ],
        [
            'prop1' => 'somevalue',
            'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
            'path' => 'used'
        ],
        [
            'prop1' => 'somevalue',
            'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
            'path' => 'used'
        ]
    ],
    'new' => [
        [
            'prop1' => 'somevalue',
            'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
            'path' => 'new'
        ],
        [
            'prop1' => 'somevalue',
            'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
            'path' => 'new'
        ],
        [
            'prop1' => 'somevalue',
            'prop2' => 'anothervalue',
            'path' => 'new'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: And what have you tried? The result does not look like filtering after all, but like seperating into multiple sub arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code lacks commas, so it's syntactically invalid. **See the updated corrected code in the demo below.** You just need this simple code:

```
<?php
  $filtered = array();
  foreach ($raw as $item) {
    $filtered[$item["path"]][] = $item;
  }
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [used] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [prop1] => somevalue
                    [prop2] => anothervalue
                    [path] => used
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [prop1] => somevalue
                    [prop2] => anothervalue
                    [path] => used
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [prop1] => somevalue
                    [prop2] => anothervalue
                    [path] => used
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [prop1] => somevalue
                    [prop2] => anothervalue
                    [path] => used
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [prop1] => somevalue
                    [prop2] => anothervalue
                    [path] => used
                )

        )

    [new] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [prop1] => somevalue
                    [prop2] => anothervalue
                    [path] => new
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [prop1] => somevalue
                    [prop2] => anothervalue
                    [path] => new
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [prop1] => somevalue
                    [prop2] => anothervalue
                    [path] => new
                )

        )

)
```

**Demo:** https://eval.in/1047516

Comment: Spot on thanks, my mistake on the example I provided, I just quickly typed that up to avoid posting actual data.

Comment: @MartynBall That's totally fine... I am glad I could help you with this... `:D`